# "ReferenceError: Jdbc is not defined" when run from function in a library

Tags: google-apps-script, jdbc

This code was working fine when it was in a function within my Google Apps Script file:

```
var jdbcConn = Jdbc.getConnection(dbAddress, dbUser, dbPswd);
```

However, when I moved that function to a library to reuse it elsewhere, I suddenly got this error:

> ReferenceError: Jdbc is not defined

When I move the routine back to my Google App Script (not using the library) - works fine.

Anything dumb I am missing? My first time trying to use a library so maybe there is some nuance I'm not understanding.

Comment: Have you searched for similar questions in tags?

Comment: Thanks I had looked at that post above and the issue tracking. Didn't seem to be much info or progress on it.

Comment: You are right. In reading the issue tracker more closely. My bad. Guess I will need to use a workaround as they describe there. Thanks TheMaster & @kos.